# git svn: "checksum mismatch" "bad revision 'HEAD'" errors

Tags: git, svn, migration

I am trying to define the best possible migration path for svn -> git.

My goal is to get a git repository:

- containing a subset of svn branches (10 branches)
- starting at a specific revision (rev29000 out of 49000)

svn will still run in read-only mode after migration so we can have the full history.

I was successful in cloning the WHOLE svn repo to git using

```
git svn clone --stdlayout --authors-file=<myauthorsfile> svn://<mySvnRepo> <myGitRepo>
```

but I prefer having a git containing the SUBSET described above, here's where the trouble starts:

- "git svn clone -r29000:HEAD ...." breaks after some hours with a bunch of "checksum mismatch" errors (similar to this: http://issues.tmatesoft.com/issue/SGT-645 )

My question: as I have successfully built a git (*gitWhole*) repo containing the WHOLE svn repo:
is it possible to rebuild a second git repo out of *gitWhole* using the constraints mentioned above (selective branches / starting at rev29000)?

Any help appreciated, "trial and error" is pretty time consuming with such large repositories.

**Edit:**

Still hitting the "Checksum mismatch" error while running the svn clone command.
I tried to fix the problem using the command

```
git svn reset -r<revnumberPrior> -p
```

where  is the svn revision before the problematic checksum.

Unfortunately all I get is the error

```
C:\git\GitMigration\PPgit>git svn reset -r31911
fatal: bad revision 'HEAD'
rev-list --first-parent --pretty=medium HEAD --: command returned error: 128
```

Any idea?

Thanks a lot & regards

Daniel

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can restrict the clone depth using `--depth N` argument, to build a new repo based on your `gitWhole` repo. This way the history will be truncated to only `N` revisions.

Comment: Thank you dan. Now I should combine this with a filter to the 10 selective branches (out of 30 approximately).